# SQL Server - Alternative To Using a Predicate In a WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to delete all of the events in my DemoTable where the difference between the first event and last event for that interaction is greater than 30 minutes. I wrote a select statement to look at all of these events and used the HAVING keyword to get the events that have a DATEDIFF of greater than 30 minutes.

Since I can't use a HAVING in a delete or use a predicate in a WHERE clause, what is the best alternative/proper way to do what I want to do in the incorrect code below...

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.DemoTable dt
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(dt.utc), MAX(dt.utc)) > 30
GROUP BY dt.interactionId;
GO
```

EDIT: Thank you to everyone for their suggestions!

Comment: Is the query you wrote in the question working?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli No the query in my question returns an error stating that a predicate is not allowed to be used in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is like this:

```
DELETE FROM
    dbo.DemoTable
WHERE
    dto.DemoTable.YourPrimaryKey IN
    (
        SELECT
            YourPrimaryKey
        FROM
            -- your query here
    )
```

This only works for non-composite primary-keys.

Comment: This works well for me, thank you! It seems like a good way to achieve what i'm trying to do, so why do you refer to it as a quick and dirty way?

Comment: @David Well, because you can't use it with composite primary keys.

Comment: Ah okay, I typically don't use composite primary keys so this is good for me :).

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the alternative is to use a temptable containing the valid data and use those data to eliminate invalid ones like below:

```
SELECT dt.interactionid
INTO #temp
FROM DemoTable dt
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(dt.utc), MAX(dt.utc)) <= 30

DELETE dt
FROM DemoTable dt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from #temp t where t.interactionid = dt.interactionid)
```

Answer (score 1):

A sub query?

```
delete from dbo.demotable
where interactionid in 
    (select dt.interactionid
    from dbo.demotable dt
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(dt.utc), MAX(dt.utc)) > 30
    GROUP BY dt.interactionId)
```

depending on the version of sql you could just delete it like so:

```
delete from dt
from dbo.demotable dt
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(dt.utc), MAX(dt.utc)) > 30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all such interactions, you can use a join or an updatable CTE.  I would go for the latter:

```
with todelete as (
      select dt.*, 
             min(dt.utc) over (partition by dt.interactionId) as min_utc,
             max(dt.utc) over (partition by dt.interactionId) as max_utc
      from dbo.DemoTable dt
     )
delete from todelete
    where datediff(day, min_utc, max_utc) > 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries

```
DELETE FROM dbo.DemoTable dt
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM dbo.DemoTable
    -- The rest of your query
)
GO
```